# Error -undefined is not a function while using Editor.datatables.net

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using jQuery datatable editor in ASP.Net. Referring the example given [here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html) I have included all the JS and CSS in the following sequence:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://editor.datatables.net/media/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/data_table_edit_delete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://editor.datatables.net/media/css/dataTables.editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But I'm getting error that `undefined is not a function` at this line:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
```

I have same code given at above link in datatable editor example. Just I'm getting data from C# rater than PHP. When I search I found that it might not finding the javascript reference. But all I used similarly to that example.

My js code in `data_table_edit_delete.js` file is:

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function () {
    // console.log($.fn.dataTable.Editor); 
   // console.log($.fn.DataTable.Editor); 

    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        "ajax": "data_table2.aspx/BindDatatable",
            "table": "#example",
            "fields": [{
            "label": "User ID:",
                "name": "UserId"
        }, {
            "label": "User Name:",
                "name": "UserName"
        }, {
            "label": "Location:",
                "name": "Location"
        }]
    });

    // New record
    $('a.editor_create').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        editor.create({
            title: 'Create new record',
            buttons: 'Add'
        });
    });

    // Edit record
    $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        editor.edit($(this).closest('tr'), {
            title: 'Edit record',
            buttons: 'Update'
        });
    });

    // Delete a record
    $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        editor.remove($(this).closest('tr'), {
            title: 'Delete record',
            message: 'Are you sure you wish to remove this record?',
            buttons: 'Delete'
        });
    });

    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: "data_table2.aspx/BindDatatable",
        columns: [{
            data: null,
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                // Combine the first and last names into a single table field
                return data.first_name + ' ' + data.last_name;
            }
        }, {
            data: "UserId"
        }, {
            data: "UserName"
        }, {
            data: "Location"
        }, {
            data: null,
            className: "center",
            defaultContent: '<a href="" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that your second example uses `DataTable`. The correct version is `dataTable`.

Comment: Actully I have tried using  editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor and  editor = new $.fn.DataTable.Editor but still same error is giving

Comment: That would cause the error you've seen if that's what you're using as Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: But I use the same code given in this link https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html

Comment: I think i need to download the library of editor for .net but that is a trial version and may need to purchase latter so is there any other way to edit delete data tables?